# To prove $1^1\cdot2^2\cdot 3^3...\cdot n^n<(\frac{2n+1}{3})^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

So we have to prove the following for $n\in N $ $$1^1\cdot 2^2\cdot 3^3...\cdot n^n<\left(\frac{2n+1}{3}\right)^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}} $$

So I used concept of weighted means (arithmetic and geometric) used AM GM inequality.

$$AM=\frac{a_1w_1+a_2w_2+...+a_nw_n}{w_1+w_2+...+w_n}$$

$$GM=(a_1^{w_1}\cdot a_2^{w_2}\cdot...\cdot a_n^{w_n})^{\frac{1}{w_1+w_2+...+w_n}}$$
So here I let $w_1=1, w_2=2^1,w_3=3^1..$ and of course $a_1=1,a_2=2^1,a_3=3^2...$

So we get:
$$\frac{1^1+ 2^2+ 3^3...+ n^n}{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}>(1^1\cdot 2^2\cdot 3^3...\cdot n^n)^{\frac{1}{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}}$$

However on lhs, I cant deal with numerator, and I feel that if it can be simplified, I would get the answer. So please help or if possible suggest new method.

Comment: From what I have just tried, the inequality seems to be false, at least for $n=1,2,3$. For $n=1:\ \ 1= 1^1 \nless \left(\frac{2\cdot1+1}{3}\right)^{\frac{1\cdot2}{3}} = 1^{2/3} =1$; for $n=2:\ \ 4=1^1\cdot2^2 \nless \left(\frac{2\cdot2+1}{3}\right)^{\frac{2\cdot3}{3}}\approx 2.78$; for $n=3:\ \ 108=1^1\cdot2^2\cdot3^3 \nless \left(\frac{2\cdot3+1}{3}\right)^{\frac{3\cdot4}{3}}\approx 29.64$

Comment: @DanielP Oops i wrote 3 instead of 2 in power, now edited

Comment: Take the log of both sides. You'll find a familiar sum on the left and a familiar product on the right.

Comment: Yup, now it seems to work for $n \ge 2$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Well ig we need to derive rhs inequality from scratch, as per question?

Comment: @KshitijKumar You shouldn't. Take the log of both sides and turn the left into a sum and the right into a simple product. Once you get the sum it almost falls into your lap.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Thank you, I did though of this, but wasn;t confident. However I would like answer which derives it from scratch.

Comment: Your stuff is right except  a typo. Your LHS should be $\left( 1\cdot1+2\cdot 2 +\cdots +  n\cdot n\right)/\text{number of terms} = \frac{2n+1}{3}$. Also AM is greater than, not less than the GM. Then raise the power of both sides.

Comment: @GiantRay Thank you very much. I goofed up in the powers and weighted w's. I got it

Comment: Perhaps you can use that $\sum_{k=1}^nk = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ so that $\left(\frac{2n+1}{3}\right)^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}} = \prod_{k=1}^n(\frac{2n+1}3)^k$.

Comment: Why were all the answers below deleted?

Comment: I deleted my answer, which attempted a proof by induction for two reasons: [1] I had an analytical error which would have taken some convoluted logic to fix.  [2] The comments' suggestion of taking the log of both sides leads to a much more elegant proof.

Comment: @user2661923 That deleted answer mixed up which of $\log n$ and $\log(\frac{2n+1}{3})$ was bigger. Despite a few users saying it does, I have yet to see how taking logs of both sides yields a proof.

Comment: @Mike I was using the answer section to check the formatting of my comment and then accidentally posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AMGM is the right idea, you just applied it wrong. As you say, the inequality is

$$ \frac{w_1x_1+\cdots+w_nx_n}{w_1+\cdots+w_n}\ge(x_1^{w_1}\cdots x_n^{w_n})^{1/(w_1+\cdots+w_n)}. $$

(If we define $p_k=w_k/(w_1+\cdots+w_n)$, this reads $p_1x_1+\cdots+p_nx_n\ge x_1^{p_1}\cdots x_n^{p_n}$.)

In your case, if you define $w_k=x_k=k$ for $k=1,\cdots,n$ the inquality becomes

$$ \frac{1^2+\cdots+n^2}{1+\cdots+n}\ge(1^1\cdots n^n)^{1/(1+\cdots+n)}. $$

Using $1+\cdots+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ and $1^2+\cdots+n^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$ you should be able to finish.

(After writing this I read up and apparently Giant Ray pointed this out in the comments.)

Comment: Nice answer...+1

Answer (score 3):

Use the AM-GM inequality [where there are $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ terms; indeed for each positive integer $i \le n$, there are $i$ terms of $i$]:

$$\frac{\sum_{1=1}^n i^2}{n(n+1)/2} \ \ge \ \sqrt[\frac{n(n+1)}{2}]{1^12^2 \cdots n^n},$$
where in the above inequality, the LHS represents the arithmetic mean of the above terms and the RHS the geometric mean of the above terms.

However, the equation
$$\frac{\sum_{1=1}^n i^2}{n(n+1)/2}  = \frac{(n)(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} \times \frac{2}{n(n+1)}$$
$$ = \frac{2n+1}{3} $$ also holds. So then combining this string of equations with the top AM-GM inequality, yields the inequality
$$\frac{2n+1}{3} \ \ge \ \sqrt[\frac{n(n+1)}{2}]{1^12^2 \cdots n^n} \ .$$

Raising each side of this to the $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$-power yields the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

*This is not a proof since working for large values of $n$*
$$\prod_{k=1}^n k^k=H(n)$$ where $H(n)$ is the hyperfactorial function.

Expanding its logarithm
$$\log (H(n))=-\frac 14 n^2+\frac 1{12} \left(6 n^2+6 n+1\right)\log(n)+\log (A)+\frac{1}{720 n^2}\left(1-\frac{1}{7 n^2}+\frac{1}{14
   n^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^6}\right) \right)$$
Doing the same for the logarithm of the rhs
$$\log\left(\frac{\text{rhs}}{\text{lhs}}\right)=\log \left(\frac{4 e}{9}\right)\,\frac{n(n+1)}4-\frac 1{12}\log(n)+\left(\frac{3}{16}-\log (A)\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$